# How can I access elements of an array with Template Toolkit?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, template-toolkit

I would like to access element of array directly using template toolkit.

e.g. 
we can easily do this,

```
[% FOREACH item IN array %]
    [% item %]
[% END %]
```

Can I access directly 0th , 1st, 2nd etc. elements without using any loop?

e.g.

```
`[% array[0] %]`
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
[% array.0 %]
```

If the index is inside a variable:

```
[% array.$index %]
```

The documentation can be found at [www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References).

Comment: It might be useful to add a documentation link.